# 「その＋名詞」ｖｓ「この＋名詞」

Tags: grammar, demonstratives

I am currently working through the N1 grammar preparation book 「新完全マスター　文法」and one of the later chapters of the book deals with the difference between 「その＋名詞」and「この＋名詞」.

There are two examples given:

For 「その＋名詞」:

> 新しい調理道具を買った。しかし、**その**使い方になれるまで時間がかかりそうだ。（「**そ**」の＝「新しい調理道具」
>
> explanation: 「その＋名詞」で「そ」が前の文章中のものを指す。

and for 「この／その＋名詞」(both can be used):

> うちの子はある有名人のお嬢さんと同級だ。**この**／**その**お嬢さんが先日うちに遊びに来た。（「**この**／**その**お嬢さん」＝「ある有名人のお嬢さん」）
>
> explanation: 「この／その＋名詞」全体で前の文章中のものを指す。

Even with reading the explanation and the two sample sentences, I do not fully understand the difference between cases where only「その＋名詞」can be used and cases where both 「この／その＋名詞」are correct. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the former example, その is working like *its* in English, where そ is *it* and の is possessive *-s*. In the latter, この/その is like *the/that/this* in English. Compare:

> - 山の中に家がありました。**その**屋根は鮮やかな赤色でした。 → その = "its (roof)"
> - 山の中に家がありました。**その/この**家には煙突がありました。 → その/この = "the/this (house)"

When その is working like *its*, it is not interchangeable with この. When その is working like *the*, この is also grammatical, although there is an obvious difference in mood (similar to the difference between "the house" and "this house" in English).