# What does そのねらいは mean in this sentence?

Tags: nouns

> 波希（なぎ）はその都度、うそをついた。「これ、お父さんの形見だから」。つまり、亡き父の眼鏡を後生大事にかけている、ちょっと変った娘を装っているのだ。  そして、**そのねらいは、** 「名塩さんって、ひょっとして眼鏡を取ったら、すごく美人だったりするんじゃない？」  と、ささやかれることにあった。

It's from a book that I'm reading. I got the whole sentence excepting "そのねらい". Does it mean "for this purpose"? I'm not sure but I think I don't understand the その before some words, like そのうち, そのうえ.

Do you think it means "[its / her aim](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/70645/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%EF%BC%8B%E5%90%8D%E8%A9%9E-%EF%BD%96%EF%BD%93-%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%EF%BC%8B%E5%90%8D%E8%A9%9E)"?

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`その` without any context usually means whatever has been mentioned in the prior sentence. In this case `そのねらい` means the "aim"/"purpose" of `ちょっと変った娘を装っている`.